# Difference between OIDC and OAuth2 in spring oauth client

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

My goal is to authenticate an user through an authentication service (like google or github).

I tried to use both, and I don't understand why with github my authentication is handled with my OAuth2UserService, while with google, this is my OidcUserService which is called.

I expect that both call OidcUserService because it's only authentification that I need.

So, why there is such a difference ?
Can you enlighten me about that ?
Do I miss something ?

Some code to illustrate

```java
@Service
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {

        OAuth2User user = super.loadUser(userRequest);

        log.info("OAuth2User loading");

        return user;
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class CustomOidcUserService extends OidcUserService {

    @Override
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {

        OidcUser user = super.loadUser(userRequest);

        log.info("OidcUser loading");

        return user;
    }
}
```

```java
// MyAppSecurityConfig.java
@Configuration
public class MyAppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
        ;
    }
}
```

```
# application.properties
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-id=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-secret=xxx

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=xxxx
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are observing caused by [predefined oauth2 configurations in spring-boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security.oauth2.client.common-providers):

> For common OAuth2 and OpenID providers, including Google, Github,
> Facebook, and Okta, we provide a set of provider defaults (google,
> github, facebook, and okta, respectively).
>
> If you do not need to customize these providers, you can set the
> provider attribute to the one for which you need to infer defaults.
> Also, if the key for the client registration matches a default
> supported provider, Spring Boot infers that as well.

i.e. spring boot has preconfigured openid-connect for google services and generic oauth2 for github.

Comment: ok, but what in the preconfiguration indicates that one uses oidc and other uses oauth2 ? and how can I configure my app for both use oidc ? Nothing seams to refer to this behavior in `CommonOAuth2Provider`..

Comment: "Nothing seams to refer to this behavior in CommonOAuth2Provider" - actually the presence of "openid" in configured scopes makes sense. If you want to override defaults you need to configure provider as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security.oauth2.client